# %= and |= Query Operator, Ext JS

Tags: javascript, extjs

There are two [Ext.ComponentQuery](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0/5.0.0-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.ComponentQuery) comparison operators (selectors) that are defined in the documentation; however, they are not explained in the documentation: `%=` and `|=`.

Does anybody have any idea what these do?

*Side Note: the reason I am asking is because I am trying to find a NOT LIKE operator for the query*

Comment: In jQuery, the `|=` operator is used in the [Attribute Contains Prefix selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-prefix-selector/). ExtJS may use it in the same way. No idea about `%=`, though.

Comment: _Attributes can use any of the following operators to compare values: =, !=, ^=, $=, *=, %=, |= and ~=._ are you refering to this?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi thank you! That gets me closer!

Comment: Those are attribute selectors, and they probably follow the [standards](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors)

Comment: @adeneo: cool, but %= is missing in the standards.. perhaps it is so pointless (or not really needed) that it is not "standard"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's the source code involved:

```
"%=": function(a, v) {
    return (a % v) === 0;
},
"|=": function(a, v) {
    return a && (a == v || a.substr(0, v.length + 1) == v + '-');
},
```

So `%=` looks for values that evenly divide the search value. (I can't recall ever needing to do this.) `|=` looks for a value that is either the same as the search value, or appears at the start of the value followed by a single hyphen character.

Examples, I think:

```
"[data-value%=2]"
```

looks for elements with a "data-value" attribute whose value is an even number.

```
"[name|=red]"
```

looks for elements with a "name" attribute whose value is "red" or anything of the form "red-something".

Comment: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0/5.0.0-apidocs/source/Operators.html#Ext-util-Operators

Comment: @CD.. yes exactly. I don't know why they would bother to type in all that documentation but then leave out those two operators.

Comment: @Pointy hence my question

Comment: @Thomas yes I understand :) I do not recall ever being in a situation where either of these would have been useful, but I guess the universe is a big place.

Comment: Yeah, they certainly aren't what I am looking for. I can understand the `|=`, but the `%=` is a bit strange. Maybe for security stuff?

Comment: @Thomas maybe for cases where attributes serve as numeric indexes, and you want to find certain subsets? I agree it seems like a rare case.

Comment: @Thomas: it's still javascript and, besides, why on Earth would you search for a value that evenly divide the search term? I'm really interested in finding a valid example where you need to use such an operator, lol. What I'm curious about, however, is _why_ they have implemented it.

Comment: @briosheje maybe the goal was something like what the CSS `nth-child()` thing does, for index attributes or something. That's all I can think of.

Comment: @Pointy: same, but this is so rare that I don't see the point of implementing it... Or maybe we just can't see much far, who knows! :P Anyway, about the OP's question, I don't think there is any operator that performs a "NOT LIKE" operation.. Perhaps he can combine some, but is there any operator for the "LIKE" part?

Comment: @briosheje I'm not sure what "NOT LIKE" means exactly, but surely there's something in Ext.js like the jQuery `.filter()` that can be used to perform arbitrary predicate selections.